# Sending message to Whatsapp API through javascript , opens whatsapp but shows blank text

Tags: javascript, api, whatsapp

This is the code I have:

```
   var txt = $((WhatsappHTML.html() + '<span> </span>').replace(/%/g,'%25').replace(/<br>/g,'%0a').replace(/&amp;/g, '%26')).text().replaceAll('  ', ' '); */
   console.log(txt);
   javascript:window.open("whatsapp://send?text="+txt,'_self');
```

When executing it, the console shows:

```
Payment Terms: 30 Days From Invoice Date%0a%0a*Specialty Item* %0a @ *1 USD/LB* CIF Holanda%0a%0a 
f:1 Launched external handler for 'whatsapp://send?text=Payment%20Terms:%2030%20Days%20From%20Invoice%20Date%0a%0a*Specialty%20Item*%20%0a%20@%20*1%20USD/LB*%20CIF%20Holanda%0a%0a'.
```

However, when the whatsapp desktop is opened, there is a blank message. It does not happen consistently, usually it shows correctly the message, but sometimes it does not.
WhatsappHTML.html(), is an object generated, but there is text in it, so the api is fired correctly.
Does anyone have any idea why is showing Whatsapp desktop app blank?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I just found out the pattern.
When you send directly a message with the launcher, if the user clicks on the "send arrow" instead of hitting "enter" to publish the comment to the destination, somehow it breaks and next time you execute the "whatsapp://sned?text=something"  will not work. I have tested this and is consistently working this way. It will always send the message only when you hit enter. This clearly is an issue on the Whatsapp API side.